# How to in kendo ui set datasource to select element?

Tags: select, kendo-ui, datasource

I have mobile app by kendo ui! And I try get select element like below

```
                <select>
                    <option value="First Option">First Option</option>
                    <option value="Second Option">Second Option</option>
                    <option value="Third Option">Third Option</option>
                    <option value="Fourth Option">Fourth Option</option>
                </select>
```

But datasouce must load remote by read url like this:

```
    $("#comboAssignment"+i).kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "Id",
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '/Reference/ListEmploye'

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `dataTextField` and `dataValueField` to the same property.  This way, the item's value and display text match like the sample you provided.

```
$("#comboAssignment"+i).kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Name",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Reference/ListEmploye'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```